# PHP no actualiza los productos

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, php7

estoy haciendo un crud de productos. he conseguido hacer el listado, el agregar y la eliminación. Pero no consigo que actualice los productos. Le he dado varias vueltas pero no consigo ver el problema. Este es el código del formulario para actualizar los productos.

```
<form action="editar.php" method="post">
    <label for="nom">Nombre</label> <br />
    <input class="col-12" type="text" required name="nom" id="nombre" value="<?= $_POST['nom'] ?>"> <br /><br />
    
    <label for="desc">descripción</label> <br />
    <input class="col-12" type="text" required name="desc" id="descripcion" value="<?= $_POST['desc']?>"> <br /><br /> 
    
    <label for="prec">precio</label> <br />
    <input class="col-12" type="text" required name="prec" id="precio" value="<?= $_POST['prec'] ?>"> <br /><br />
    
    <input class="btn btn-primary col-12" type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

Y este el archivo que se encarga de actualizar los productos. Los tengo en archivos separados.

```
<?php
include("conexion.php");
$conn = conexion();

$nombre = $_POST["nom"];
$descripcion = $_POST["desc"];
$precio = intval($_POST["prec"]);

$query = "UPDATE productos SET nombre = '$nombre', descripcion='$descripcion', precio='$precio' WHERE id = '$_POST[id]'";

mysqli_query($conn, $query);

header("location:index.php");
?>
```

Comment: Una consulta DELETE no actualiza nada, más bien elimina datos. Arregla la consulta y arreglarás el problema seguramente.

Comment: Ese código PHP elimina un registro, no lo actualiza... Para actualizar deberías usar la cláusula [`UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)

Comment: Ya lo he corregido. Me he equivocado al copiar el código. Pido disculpas

Comment: Esa consulta es correcta. Hay algún error de MySQL?

Comment: No estas pasando el $_POST['id']. Mételo en un `<input type="hidden"`

Comment: @julio Me refiero a que no está en el formulario

Comment: O en el `action=editar.php?id=1`, y cambiar `$_POST['id']` por `$_GET['id']`

Comment: @masterguru si si, no leí bien el form

Comment: @julio Entonces no seria POST

Comment: Sí, ese era el problema. No estaba pasando el id del producto. No sé cómo no lo he visto

Comment: @masterguru y que le meta un `$_GET`